# Datagridview multi line textbox when ctrl+enter press

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, multiline

I'm trying to add some specific behavior to a `datagridview` control (if you can put it like that).

I would like to have a `multiplelines` `textbox` control in the `datagridview`. I achieved this when giving a string that is too long to fit in the `textbox`, it's automatic placed on a second line.

So the steps would be enter text into a cell, while the focus is on the cell press ctrl+enter so that the text entered next is on a second line.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
```

But I would also be able to force a second line by pressing `ctrl + enter key` On this matter my internet search came up empty.

I guess it would be catching the key press event within a cell but I can't seem to find this event.

[Possible events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx)

I tried this event, but it only happens when the `Datagridview` in total is selected.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyPress
     ' Some magic here.
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried "Shift-Enter" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am fairly confident you can achieve the desired results by changing a couple of properties in the `DataGridView` and use a “Shift-Enter” instead of “Ctrl-Enter”.

In the `DataGridView` set its `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `AllCells`, then set the particular COLUMNS `DefaultCellStyle` -> `WrapMode` to true. Then use a “Shift-Enter” while editing a cell and you should get multiple lines in a cell. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how to resize the row directly when the shift-enter occurs?

Comment: If the `DataGridView` `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set to `AllCells` or `DisplayedCells`, then as soon as you click away from the edited cell it should resize the just edited row to fit the text. I am guessing this is what you mean. Unfortunately, when `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set to `AllCells` then the user will not be able to resize the rows before editing..

Comment: This is what I mean, but it is not possible to have the row resized before clicking away?

Comment: I could not get it to work that way without simply typing in some extra returns then clicking away then back. I am sure this is because the rows are set to auto size and it wont know how may rows it is until the user leaves the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the C# syntax. But I guess the event exists also in VB.NET.

I would suggest to use the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I have been Executed!");
    }
}
```

this works for me catching keyboard input when the `DataGridView` has focus.

Comment: Hi, I may not have been clear so I updated my question. I want to add a newline while typing into a cell by press ctrl+enter. So that I can choose what portion of my text is on a new line and not only on how it fits the cell.