# how to move cursor in datagridview moves to next line on same row cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview

what i need to do is to make the user enter his data in datagridview in each cell, when typing in a cell and clicks enter from keyboard it moves to the next line in same cell to type another line. this code below i used to add one more line on cell and it works, but the problem with me that i want to move to the next line on same cell to type the next line but when clicks arrow down or enter it goes to next row

```
    dataGridView1.RowCount = 4;
           dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

          //  dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            for(int r=0;r<4;r++)
            {
                for(int c=0;c<3;c++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value + Environment.NewLine;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value + Environment.NewLine;


                }
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035138/14171304

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datagridview multi line textbox when ctrl+enter press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395264/datagridview-multi-line-textbox-when-ctrlenter-press)